# "Course in/on/of/for nursing specialty"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which preposition would be the correct one?

> the course **in/on/of/for** nursing speciality

Answer (score 2):

If you are studying fish, you can follow a course **on** fish.

If you want to teach fish how to swim, you can give a course **to** fish. The course is intended **for** fish.

If you are eating, you can have a course **of** fish.

And if you are following a course *inside* a really big fish, you could say it is a course **in** fish.

Comment: Just to make it clear, prepositions are used to specify the type of relationship between the nouns, and normally the nouns can be used with multiple ones.